# Getting error while inserting in MySQL table using Python MYSQL.Connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

This is my code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO haircolor (x_pos, y_pos, width, height,filename,hair_color) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

print ("Values",(x_pos, y_pos, width, height,filename,hair_color))
mycursor.execute(sql, (x_pos, y_pos, width, height,filename,hair_color))
mydb.commit()
```

Output:

> Values: 33.897543, 28.304444444444444, 2.7566544, 4.9043634, '1 (copy1).jpg`,`black`

Error

> Failed processing format-parameters python 'str_' cannot be converted to a mysql type

Comment: I tried. Same error

Comment: Thanks for the idea. haircolor was numpy array

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as though you have un-escaped back quotes in your filename and haircolour variables ... that won't help anything ...